# How to solve the error in the reading file /root/.config/user-dirs.dirs while installing the new app?

Tags: system-installation

while installing a new app I hit the command properly but I am facing this problem.
This the code :
root@adminsystem:/home/dipen/Downloads# chmod +x Tracker-5.1.5-linux-64bit-installer.run
root@adminsystem:/home/dipen/Downloads# ./Tracker-5.1.5-linux-64bit-installer.run

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same problem in Debian Bullseye.

To solve it, try to install `xdg-user-dirs` (automatic installed in my case) and run `sudo xdg-user-dirs-update`.

Also, you're going to need to run `sudo ./Tracker-5.1.5-linux-64bit-installer.run`